# Keeping Multiple Servers in a Cluster In-Sync?

Tags: linux, ssh, rsync

I'm currently managing a cluster of PHP-FPM servers, all of which tend to get out of sync with each other. The application that I'm using on top of the app servers (Magento) allows for admins to modify various files on the system, but now that the site is in a clustered set up modifying a file only modifies it on a single instance (on one of the app servers) of the various machines in the cluster.

Is there an open-source application for Linux that may allow me to keep all of these servers in sync? I have no problem with creating a small VM instance that can listen for changes from machines to sync. In theory, the perfect application would have small clients that run on each machine to be synced, which would talk to the master server which would then decide how/what to sync from each machine.

I have already examined the possibilities of running a centralized file server, but unfortunately my app servers are spread out between EC2 and physical machines, which makes this unfeasible. As there are multiple app servers (some of which are dynamically created depending on the load of the site), simply setting up a rsync cron job is not efficient as the cron job would have to be modified on each machine to send files to every other machine in the cluster, and that would just be a whole bunch of unnecessary data transfers/ssh connections.

Answer (score 1):

I'm dealing with setting up a similar solution.  I'm half way there.  I would recommend you use lsyncd, which basically monitors the disk for changes and then immediately (or whatever interval you want) automatically syncs files to a list of servers using rsync.

The only issue I'm having is keeping the server lists up to date, since I can spin up additional servers at any time, I would need to have each machine in the cluster notified whenever a machine is added or removed from the cluster.

I think lsyncd is a great solution that you should look into.  The issue I'm having may turn out to be a problem for you as well, and that remains to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of keeping tens or hundreds of servers cross-synchronized it would be much more efficient, reliable, and most of all simple maintaining just *one* "admin node" and replicating changes from that to all your "worker nodes".

For instance at our company we use a Development server -> Staging server -> Live backends workflow where all the changes are transferred across servers using a custom php+rsync front end. That allows the developers to push updates to a Staging server in the live environment, test out changes, and roll them to Live backends incrementally.

A similar approach could very well work in your case as well. Obviously it's not a plug-and-play solution, but I see it as the easiest way to go - both in terms of maintainability and scalability.

Comment: While I agree with this approach, in my cluster the staging environment would be eliminated and the changes should be available immediately. The problem with the rsync method is detecting changes from the various servers. I was thinking about writing a simple python script to tell a master server to execute rsync commands on changes....

Comment: Indeed. I mentioned our setup just as a reference. There's no need for having a separate staging server. However doing the changes on just one, dedicated server is definitely the way to go. Rsyncing the changes from that one server across the cluster is a breeze. You could, for instance, write a shell script to loop over an array of your cluster nodes and do `rsync /www/directory/ remote:/www/directory` to each one. That could be run in cron or triggered over HTTP on need-to-run basis.

Comment: The only problem I see with this approach is the unnecessary amount of network requests that will be made. With my cluster setup it is not possible to have a master app server, as it is in a round robin configuration. However, I am considering using an NFS caching solution to keep the machines in sync.

Comment: I see. A master-slave(s) solution would work very well in your case, so it might be worth considering if it's worth implementing. Rsync only transfers data that has been changed, so the amount of network traffic is next to nil compared to regular traffic. I'd be extra cautious with relaying on NFS to share data. You'll easily end up being stuck with stale NFS handles and possibly locking issues.